# Decode Large base64 text string in C#

Tags: c#, base64

I have Large base64 encoded text file I need to know  in C#.Net

How do I decode this large string into a string?

I use this Code but it take long time, and sometimes it got frozen and stop responding

```
richTextBox2.Text = Base64Decode(richTextBox1.Text); // I Past text at richTextBox1
```

and I try this too

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(richTextBox1.Text);
var text = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
richTextBox2.Text = text.ToString();
```

there are many similar Questions but I find no one talk about large text files

Edit:

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried decoding it async?

Comment: How large is large and how long is long?

Comment: I don't think so. can You explain how ?

Comment: it is 323 pages. (about 1 MB)

Comment: it takes long time - more than 4 min - sometimes it take forever

Comment: What does `Base64Decode` do? Just calling `Convert.FromBase64String` really shouldn't take too long. Note that *displaying* 323 pages in a single text box may well be the problem. You should isolate *exactly* which call is causing the problem.

Comment: sorry, this is Base64Decode

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
        {
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }

Comment: 1MB isn't a lot of data. Have you timed the call? Are you sure the problem isn't the delay in loading 1MB of text to the RichTextBox control?

Comment: I try Copy/Past Text in the RichBox then after I Press Decode Button it the delay happened

Comment: @user3570328 Then you are timing the entire operation of decoding *and* displaying the text on the RTB control. Use  [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to time how long the Decode function takes in code

Comment: I did a test using simultaneously backgroundWorkers. Basically i have splitted a large b64String (read by a streamreader into a memorystream a huge file: 625MB) in 16000 strings and then i started multiples backgroundworkers to convert splitted strings. Despite time elapsed to split and rejoin, i did noticed an improvment of 1 second compared to the time spent to convert whole file just with Convert.FromBase64. The same test on a smaller file and less splits (600Kb with 64 bgworkers) as expected gave me the opposite result -> 0ms for Convert.FromBase64 and 8ms for splitted workers.

Comment: Please note.. convert 625MB take 2376ms with workers, and 3675ms with direct convert. As pointed out by @PanagiotisKanavos i think your problem it's on displaiyng large text instead of conversion

Comment: @FrancescoMilani BackgroundWorker is an entire Component wrapped around a simple thread. You pay more for the overhead than you actually gain - and the resulting code is hideous. If you want to improve performance use Tasks or PLINQ.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i know.. :-) i didn't want to do.. i used bgworkers for a quick test, my point was "i think you can't have problem during conversion of 1MB if 625MB take less than 4 secs ;-)"

Comment: @FrancescoMilani I think You are Right .. part of the problem is Displaying the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every entire 4 bytes in base-64 represents exactly 3 bytes of original payload, with zero padding. So if the issue is doing everything at once, just think of some multiple of 4 (4 thousand, for example, or 4 * 1024), and process the data in batches of that much (or however much is left, otherwise).

However, 1MB is *not* a large amount of data; I would not expect this to be the problem. From the following:

```
    var data = new byte[10000000];
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    watch.Reset();
    watch.Start();
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I get 30ms to base-64 encode 10,000,000 bytes, and 50ms to base-64 decode the string (length: 13,333,336 characters).

Comment: Thank, But I want this for (Windows Forms Application) - how can I make it work?

Comment: @user converting between base-64 and binary works the same no matter where you are. The delay you are seeing: is not due to conversion

Answer (score -4):

Use BackgroundWorker to do the job.

Comment: Using a background thread wrapped in a Component class won't make a single BCL call go any faster, nor does it offer any advantage over simply making the call inside a Tas, using `async/await` to update the UI afterwards.

Comment: Additionally, it won't fix the problem if it's the RichTextBox control that delays in loading 1MB of text. This will always happen on the UI thread

Comment: Ok, he can transfer contents of RichTextBox in string and then send this string as parameter to BackgroundWorker. I understood that delay is caused by the base64 decoding and not the I/O with rich control.